# how to print data in wcf service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

Actually in my .asmx webservice I am printing data using     Context.Response.Write. like this:

```
  Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Context.Response.Write(@" {""Status"":""true"",""RefferalCode"" : """ + RefferalCode + @"""}");
```

but in my wcf service how to print data like above format.

Comment: It is not clear which type of service do you have. Is it REST service with webHttp behavior, or SOAP service? For rest service you can get same. **WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse**. But you are not supposed to write anything there, you should return an object with data contract, which would be serialized into JSON automatically.

Comment: This is very basic introduction into WCF REST (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide). Now it is preferable using **ASP.NET Web API** (google it) for building REST services. it is much easier and flexible.